# How to make a Cell Read Only in Excel without Password using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, cell

I'm trying to set a few specific cells read-only.

How do I lock a specific "selection" (say cell) in Excel? I don't want to use password. I want to make them Read Only.

Comment: It might have been a good idea to provide the range you were wanting to 'lock'.

Comment: The Locked cells you are referring only applies after you protect the worksheet. You can Protect a worksheet with blank password anyway. Alternatively you can add ranges that are editable without password for a person/security group and protect the worksheet with a password. What I think you should do is only allow editing on some cells and then protect the worksheet.

Comment: @RBT  [Read Only Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readonly)

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is through Data Validation. After you have a cell populated with the desired contents, Choose Data Validation and use the Custom option. For the formula enter =""

Comment: It does kinda work (trying to edit the field(s) yields "The user has restricted the values that can be entered"), however it's worth noting that the OP has been asking for a VBA based solution.